# is it possible to integrate a desktop application in a Web application?

Tags: saas, eai

I have retail POS (Place of service) system implemented in .net and java swing versions. This is desktop application. Is it possible to integrate this into Web portal/application using some EAI/ middleware tools? or is there any approach to make it online with out redeveloping UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of integration are you talking about? If about accessing data from/to then that should be feasible and there can be plenty of approach/tools/solutions for the same.

> or is there any approach to make it
>   online with out redeveloping UI?

You can look at virtualized applications/desktops solutions (e.g [Citrix XenApp](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/feature.asp?contentID=2300358), [VMware Desktop as Service](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/desktop/)) where your desktop applications can be made available over internet.

Comment: Thanks. IF it is about accessing data then what approach or tools can be used? Do I need to re write UI using ASP/JSP/HTML in such a case?. I am not looking for application virtualization solutions.

Comment: @indra, scope of what you have to do is unclear. Do you want to share some data from POS system with *other* web application or you want to recreate POS UI (complete or part of) on web based platform. If later then UI had to be re-written. You may able to use existing business logic based on POS code organization. If there is separate well written business layer then re-using it is possible and simpler. If you have business logic in a separate tier (AppServer kind of setup) then job is even simpler. Both native UI and web UI can use same tier to update/access data.

Comment: POS does not share data with other application. It talks to a DB. Thanks for the clarification.